# 2 Stroke engine magneto ignition system

Tags: ignition, small-engine, ignition-coil, two-stroke

I've got a 2 stroke 1 cylinder engine and its ignition system doesn't seem to work. 
I'm having problems with my magneto ignition system and I need help connecting everything up. I think I've connected everything right, but it still doesn't work. Am I missing another part like another coil? Should i replace it all or could you guide me how to fix it?

Edit (a little more info): It's an old soviet engine from a moped. I got it from my grandpa and i have never seen it work. I have tested the spark plug in a different engine, it works. I have tested for the spark (taking out the spark plug, touching the thread to the heatsink and trying to start it) it does not work. I have tried connecting a multimeter to the coil and i've gotten 1-3VAC. The carburator works flawlessly, the only problem i found was the spark.

Edit 2: I have tried to mostly rewire it all, I have replaced the capacitors to 2x 0.5uF capacitors wired in series. Tried to crank the engine and no dice, didn't produce a spark. The HV coil(the one that connects to the spark plug) when measuring to ground has a huge resistance of ~5mOhm while the other coil (LV i think, but not sure, the one that connects to the switch) has ~0.5Ohm. Are the coils wired up the wrong way or are they dead? (Sorry for a little sloppy soldering job in the new picture)

[image: The coil and capacitors]
[image: Rewired system]
[image: **Magneto ignition system**]

[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Is this engine on a motor vehicle?

Comment: @David - If you're wondering if it is on topic, the answer is yes, it's on topic, whether it's on a motor vehicle or not.

Comment: Thanks, @Paulster. I see on the Help meta that it is indeed within scope.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94127/discussion-on-question-by-potatoman-2-stroke-engine-magneto-ignition-system).

Comment: @PotatoMan - Your question about the magnets increases my confusion about the design.  I just assumed the magnet was in (only) one lobe of the  flywheel; the opposite lobe being a counterweight.  In the pix, though, the wrap-around shape of the coil's core now makes me think that the magnet includes both flywheel lobes.   Aside from 'why would they do that?', I'd expect it to spark every half-revolution of the crank, which seems like a bad idea.  So, cognitive dissonance.

Comment: @George maybe those yellow/orange components were just fried diodes, which made it spark only once/revolution? If they were, i need to buy new ones, because they are definitely dead.

Comment: @PotatoMan - I don't understand magnetics well enough to answer that.  And, it wouldn't explain why there are two.  And, even if so, and it's just a matter of replacing 'diodes', the specs would be important - PIV, in particular.  Is there any chance of finding a service manual for this (or similar) machine?

Comment: @George nope, I don't think so, it's a motor which was probably made somewhere around the 80's and it's been in the garage for a few decades now, all it has on the engine is it's serial number, which didn't give any results on google.

Comment: @PotatoMan - On further reflection, (1) it will only fire when the points operate; so, once per cycle (what a relief); (2) that should happen at ~TDC; (3) that should correspond to maximum change in the magnetic flux; so, I'd try aligning the flywheel lobes with the coil core ends at that same TDC; (4) isn't the flywheel keyed to the crankshaft anyway?

Comment: @George (chat might not be sending notifications i have no clue, using it for the first time, so i'm just going to comment here from now on) No, the magnet is stuck on the crank tightly, but the cam can be unbolted and moved quite easily

Comment: @PotatoMan - WRT ID'ing the yellow components, it might be worthwhile to post a question on electronics.stackexchange, with a couple of the pix and your last schematic.

Comment: Okay, i'll do that

Comment: @George i think those coils produce somewhere around 6V and 12W(when i've done extended research in to the engine) and after ~1.5h of digging in the garage i have found another coil with a wire to the sparkplug, so i will test it out today if I'll have time and tell the results

Comment: @PotatoMan - If you post over there, I'd be sure to say that it's a Russian design.  That might pique more interest.

Comment: @George Thank you very much for your help, and it turns out, while my multimeter couldn't read the voltage after those 2 orange components, they were working fine.(it was such a dumb mistake) I did miss another coil and when i connecte everything up, i finally saw a spark!

Comment: @PotatoMan Congrats.  If you have the time/inclination, you might post that new info as an answer. (picture; or, especially a schematic with the additional coil.)  It all adds to the store of knowledge.  Plus, I'd be very interested to see it.

Comment: @George okay, i will do that when i have some time and actually try to run the engine, because right now it's in pieces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with the ignition was that i was missing another High Voltage coil, but before knowing that i had replaced the capacitor, bolts, sanded everything clean, so the connections would be good. As of now, the ignition works, but my timing is a little off and I'm having a few problems with my carburator so, it hasn't been started yet. (I still have problems starting it so that's why I took so long to write this answer) Some pictures to show the Ignition system as a whole: 
[[image: Main System[1]]
[image: The HV Coil]
[image: Sparkplug with its wire]
[image: The Schematic]

Comment: If you ever have the time/inclination, I'd be very interested if you could show a schematic with the new coil.  I'm having trouble following the wires in these pix, but it seems like maybe there are some changes from the original drawing?  Thanks.

Comment: One thing - it looks like the two replacement caps are wired in series.  If so, and in case you don't know, putting caps in series reduces the net capacitance by 1/2.

Comment: I totally forgot about the schematic, I'll draw it and add it. I couldn't find the appropriate ~250nF cap, so i bought 2x 500nF.

Comment: @George I have no idea about the coil windings, but the schematic looks about right now and I've also added an on/off switch.

Comment: Thanks.  I think it probably is an 'energy transfer' ignition, though I remain puzzled as to what benefit that provides.  But that's my problem.  I may post about it in some other forum.  If I do, would it be OK if I use your pix?

Comment: A final question: does this bike have any other electrical devices - lights, for instance?  And, if it does, do you know how they're powered?

Comment: @George Yeah, of course you can use the pics, but I have no idea if the bike had any other devices connected, because i only got the bare engine, but i have spotted somewhere on the forums, that the generator should produce somewhere ~12W at 6V, which can then feed the ignition and light, if there were any.

Comment: And i also forgot to mention, that what the forums said the generator should produce, i measured nowhere close to that value, I've received ~2V, but it also might be (it's just a guess) that the voltage isn't level and it's jumping/rev making a square wave or something like that

Comment: Ah - it's a generator, too.  The 'new' HV coil is the dark cylinder on the left in the second pic above?  And, does the first pic show that coil plugged onto a stud terminal on the side of the housing?  Is that terminal isolated from the case, or is it grounded?  ... I ask because the whole thing would look a lot like an old auto ignition if the points were interrupting the ground to the primary of the HV coil.  Then, the other coil(s) and flywheel magnet might be acting just as a generator.

Comment: Yes, the HV coil is the black cylinder and its stud is not connected to ground. It probably just is an old auto ignition/generator system

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a giant answer just to realize that I was putting my foot in my mouth.

What you have there is a magneto points and breaker ignition. I can't tell where the sparkplug connects but if I had to guess it is to the wire from the coil to the left bottom stud in the picture. Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Your connections (with the above assumptions) are correct. The top left stud is then used to shut the moped off by grounding it. Leave it unconnected externally to run.

Make sure that the points are clean and not burned. Also check, double check and, triple check the capacitor. That is going to be the week link in the system. If the capacitor is bad it will keep the system from sparking.

[image]

This is what I would expect the wiring to look like. Please note the "expect" part. This is what a typical points ignition would look like normally.

Comment: Yes, the spark plug should connect at the bottom left. I have checked the capacitor and it looks like its capacitance is ~220nF (i have no clue if it's still good or not, so i might buy a new one). Thank you for the clarification of the "shut down" stud and does the system look complete or am i missing another part? I have seen similar systems which have another coil.

Comment: @PotatoMan To the best of what I can see from the picture it looks complete. The coils should have a connection to the chassis somewhere. This may be internal.

Comment: Yes, it has a connection to chassis. Good to hear that's its complete. I'll try to change the capacitor tomorrow, change some wires, clean everything up and see if it helps, thank you.

Comment: I have tried changing the capacitor, but it didn't help.

Comment: @PotatoMan check the points. Do they open and close cleanly? What is the contact resistance? Are they in time (do the points open on or just after TDC)? If all of that checks out it might be the coil, that's where things get difficult.

Comment: It works good, resistance is practically 0. It's probably in time, but I'm not sure and nevertheless, I'm testing it while the spark plug is out, I don't think timing matters yet, although i'm pretty sure it is in time. Could it be as simple as me messing up the coil wires? Cause the resistance that i got, doesn't check out when i compare it to George's comment.

Comment: @PotatoMan Timing matters because you want the points to open when the magnets are flying by. If the points open when the magnets are long gone then nothing will happen. On the coil can you tell the difference between the two windings, skinny wire vs fat wire? How many wires are the chassis connection point?

Comment: The timing is set a little bigger than i think should be(it stays on for longer), yes, there's a fat wire, which i think has way more windings than the skinny one(on the top, which windings are clearly visible in the photo), one of the coil wires are soldered to the core and it's connected to the chassis via a bolt. When the points open the south and north of the magnet seems to be aligned.

Comment: My mistake, i meant, the skinny wire which is shown on the top has way more windings i think

Comment: The skinny wire with more windings should be connected to the spark plug. Is the fat wire grounded or the skinny wire grounded or both?

Comment: Oh, yeah, might've made a typo, the skinny wire is connected  to the sparkplug, but it's not connected to ground while the fat one is grounded. The coil has only 2 wires+1ground soldered, so i'm thinking now that i'm missing a wire, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @PotatoMan Check the resistance of the coil wire to ground.

Comment: The skinny wire(which is connected to the spark plug) has a resistance of ~5mOhm

Comment: @PotatoMan just to verify that's milliohm, as in way less than 1 ohm? I would expect something in the hundreds of ohms to thousands of ohms. Five milliohms is way too low. Maybe a misswire or shorted coil. I'm going to add a picture to my post.

Comment: I meant megaOhm, so almost no connection to ground

Comment: @PotatoMan Mega (capital M by the way) is too high. There might be an open in the coil or the return path to ground is missing. Do you see where the other end of the skinny wire goes?

Answer (score 0):

(More an extended comment than an answer, but whatever ...)

1. If you haven't done so, I would check the points.  Typical gaps are 0.020" (0,5 mm?)
2. I have trouble seeing spark when turning the engine by hand.  So, I do it in a dark place, and (if possible) crank the engine with a drill.
3. Re whether you need an additional coil: there are ignition systems that do, called 'Energy transfer ignition'.  [This article](https://www.motorcycleproject.com/text/ignitiontech.html), has some description of these, and says

> Energy transfer is found on most vintage offroad bikes, scooters and ATVs

All I can say is 'maybe'.  I don't know anything about them; and, just looking at your picture, I don't see where the additional coil would fit.  But, I'm coming from profound ignorance.

Comment: I have checked the gap, it looks good, i am cranking the engine currently with a drill (because i don't have a pull start or anything like that). I will try out changing some wires and a capacitor today, crank the engine in a dark place and check for the spark. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have taken it out of the cage right now and i see the skinny wire coil connect in series to another skinny wire coil through 2 what it looks like capacitors and that coil has ~5kOhm resistance to ground. I will attach a photo to the question shortly

this was meant to be a comment, but i pressed answer by accident

Answer (score 0):

(extended comment, really - elaborating/questioning my own last comment on your answer, WRT being 'an old auto ignition')

1. Configuring as such would require a significant change to the wiring you now have.  (cf "[wiring diagram](https://stickerdeals.net/wiring-diagram/ignition-coil-wiring-diagram/)", with the output of your diodes replacing the battery.)  In particular, the 'ground' terminal of the HV coil would be wired to the points, replacing the wire from the 'first' coil. So, if you trust that the present wiring is as it came originally, this idea seems like wishful thinking on my part.
2. If the wiring history is uncertain - so the HV coil 'ground' *might* properly be wired to the points - then what is to be done with the resulting disconnected end of the 'first' coil?  All I see is to ground it.  Is there any provision for that?  And, the behavior of the 'second' coil in that case is unclear to me.  There should be current in the (shorted) first coil, but it's not clear that any voltage would be induced in the second.  If not, no generator.
3. As shown in the above-referenced link, the HV coil would need 2 terminals in addition to the HV cable - namely 'battery' (connect to the diodes in your case), and 'ground'.  Is the HV 'ground' connection (as show in your schematic) brought out on a wire?

Comment: Firstly sorry for taking so long to respond, but i think the wiring is correct, it shouldn't need a battery or anything like that, I am getting a spark(sometimes misfires, but a spark nonetheless). The ground on the HV coil is just it's case/core.

Comment: It sounds like this question is resolved, then?  (The answer being that the additional coil was required, as you discovered.)  If misfire is now the problem, you might want to start a new thread - this one has gotten pretty tangled.  (Largely my doing, but that can't be helped now.)